# How to use the META Api (Graph Api) correctly to get informations from the ad library?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I want to retrieve information from the ad library. But I'm not sure how to insert the  snippet into my project. I am not good at React.js. Now I am just trying to load the SDK:

```
const ConversationPage = () => {

    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function (d) {
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
        }(document));

        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
              appId            : '424766729906560',
              autoLogAppEvents : true,
              xfbml            : true,
              version          : 'v4.0'
            })
          }
```

I know it's wrong. A button should be the trigger to get the objects back with all info:

```
const onSubmit = async () => {
        FB.api(
            '/ads_archive',
            'get',
            {"search_terms":"Anlagenmechaniker","ad_type":"EMPLOYMENT_ADS","ad_reached_countries":"['DE']"},
            function(response: any) {
                if (response && !response.error) {
                    console.log(response);
                } else {
                    console.error(response);
                }
            }
          );
        //Ignore that -> const response = await axios.post("/api/Scrape");
    }
```

That's the error:

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5LMc.png)

This should be good:

```
FB.api(
            '/ads_archive',
            'get',
            {"search_terms":"Anlagenmechaniker","ad_type":"EMPLOYMENT_ADS","ad_reached_countries":"['DE']"},
            function(response: any) {
                // Hier wird die Antwort der Graph API verarbeitet
                if (response && !response.error) {
                    console.log(response); // Hier können Sie die Antwort in der Konsole anzeigen
                    // Fügen Sie Ihren Code hier ein, um die Antwort zu verarbeiten
                } else {
                    console.error(response); // Fehlermeldung anzeigen
                }
            }
          );
```

Got it from the Facebook Graph.